# why the firewalld add port and ip witle list not working as expect

Tags: linux, firewall

Today I want to expose my cloud redis into public network, for some security reason, I just want my specific ip could access the redis port 6379. Now I do it in my cloud host like this:

```
firewall-cmd --new-zone=special --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-source=61.173.91.1/32 --permanent
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-port=6379/tcp --permanent
firewall-cmd --reload
```

to my surprise, after I startup the firewalld service, I still not able to connect the redis service. My local public ip is:

```
61.173.91.244
```

where is going wrong and what should I do to make it work?

Comment: Do you get an error message when you try to connect to Redis, and if so, which? Is there a firewall **around** the server (for example, security group in AWS)? Is Redis listening at the server's IP address and port 6379?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

expand the ip range:

```
firewall-cmd --zone=special --add-source=61.173.91.1/24 --permanent
```

works.